# How to use emoji picker plugin from editor in Joomla in a textarea field?

Tags: component, plugin, joomla-4.x, editor

I need to use the emoji picker plugin from editor to add emojis in a textarea field. Is it possible?
It's for my chat component: https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/communication/chat/tabapapo/

Comment: What emoji picker plugin?

Comment: In Joomla 4.x on the WYSIWYG TinyMCE Editor has a new emoticons picker. I want to use only this button.

Comment: Does your component even use TinyMCE?